# Postgres: como pasar datos de una base a otra sin dblink

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo que extraer algunos datos de una tabla en una base y luego, por medio de una función, cargarlos en la otra.

```
SELECT set_datos(
    param_1,
    param_2
) FROM (
    "Los datos que vienen de la otra base"
) alias
;
```

El servididor no tiene dblink y tampoco tengo permisos de administrador
¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

En principio no necesitas instalar todo el dblink, yo he podido hacer conexion a otra base solo creando la función que se necesita para esta tarea, claro asumo que si tienes permisos de crear funciones.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.dblink(
    text,
    text)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
'$libdir/dblink', 'dblink_record'
  LANGUAGE c VOLATILE STRICT
  COST 1
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION public.dblink(text, text)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

y para hacer una consulta :

```
SELECT tabla.campo
   FROM dblink('host=127.0.0.1 dbname=base user=usuario password=contraseña', 
   'SELECT campó FROM tabla') tabla(campo character varying(50));
```

Donde la primer parte lleva los datos de tu conexión, si la base esta en el mismo servidor usa la ip o el 127.0.0.1 no **'localhost**' puede dar problemas usándolo así, después una subconsulta que trae los datos que requieres y por ultimo el nombre y el tipo de datos que traerás de la otra base.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Lo probaré.

Comment: Claro espero haberte ayudado!